# How to control MT4 from python?

Tags: python, distributed-computing, mt4

I'm using a MetaTrader4 Terminal and I'm experienced python developer.

Does anyone know, how can I connect MT4 and Python? 
I want to:
- connect to MT4
- read USD/EUR data
 - make order (buy/sell)

Does anyone know some library, a page with instructions or a documentation or have at least idea how to do that?

I googled first 30 page but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do that but the best is to use `WebSocket`. as `WebSocket` provides two-way communication, it will be easy to fetch data using `MT4 EA` and send them to the `WebSocket`. You can record every `Tick` from `EA` and send it to `WebSocket`. The `WebSocket` should be opened by your Python script. You will be able to command the `EA` from python script as well. There will be a bi-directional data stream from `EA` to `Python`. There is a WebSocket library available for `MQL` you can read the [MT4 WebSocket Library](https://www.mql5.com/en/blogs/post/706665) post and for python, you can just go through the [Python WebSocket](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) from RedHat.

Comment: You have to change Python Websocket link with the correct one (https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), actually edit you response doesn't work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As of to-date, I recommend https://github.com/darwinex/dwxconnect, it enables anyone to write trading strategies in any programming language and trade them via MetaTrader 4 or 5 without having to code algorithms in MQL.

The only thing I found missing in the above recommendation was ability to get custom indicator data from MT4/5 to the preferred programming language. I did find https://github.com/khramkov/MQL5-JSON-API which allowed this. However MQL5-JSON-API was a bit complex for my taste or rather required a lot more effort to implement. How this helps

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

- exchange with files (write data from mt4 into a file for python, another folder in opposite direction with buy/sell instructions);
- 0MQ (or something like that) as a better option.